# Why Is android-support-v4.jar Not Added In Buck AntennaPod Example?

Tags: python, buck

I am working through the [AntennaPod](https://buckbuild.com/article/exopackage.html) and looking at how it builds the `submodules` folder.

[image]

There is a jar file `android-support-v4.jar` that is part of this project.

I don't see anywhere in the code where this .jar is actually added. I also don't see it in the `buck-out/bin` folder.

Here is the `android_library` step for it:

```
android_library(
  name = 'dslv-lib',
  srcs = glob(['submodules/dslv/library/src/**/*.java']),
  deps = [
    ':all-jars',
    ':dslv-res',
  ],
)
```

I see that its fetching the java files, and it depends on all-jars and the dslv-res rule. But all-jars only grabs the jars in the libs folder (which doesnt have the support-v4.jar).

**My question is:** Why is this `android-support-v4.jar`  not being added (or am I missing something), and what would be the build rule to add it?

Full AntennaPod code from Buck example is below:

```
import re

jar_deps = []
for jarfile in glob(['libs/*.jar']):
  name = 'jars__' + re.sub(r'^.*/([^/]+)\.jar$', r'\1', jarfile)
  jar_deps.append(':' + name)
  prebuilt_jar(
    name = name,
    binary_jar = jarfile,
  )

android_library(
  name = 'all-jars',
  exported_deps = jar_deps,
)

presto_gen_aidls = []
for aidlfile in glob(['src/com/aocate/presto/service/*.aidl']):
  name = 'presto_aidls__' + re.sub(r'^.*/([^/]+)\.aidl$', r'\1', aidlfile)
  presto_gen_aidls.append(':' + name)
  gen_aidl(
    name = name,
    aidl = aidlfile,
    import_path = 'src',
  )

android_library(
  name = 'presto-aidls',
  srcs = presto_gen_aidls,
)


android_build_config(
  name = 'build-config',
  package = 'de.danoeh.antennapod',
)

APP_CLASS_SOURCE = 'src/de/danoeh/antennapod/AppShell.java'

android_library(
  name = 'main-lib',
  srcs = glob(['src/de/danoeh/antennapod/**/*.java'], excludes = [APP_CLASS_SOURCE]),
  deps = [
    ':all-jars',
    ':dslv-lib',
    ':presto-lib',
    ':appcompat',
    ':build-config',
    ':res',
  ],
)

android_library(
  name = 'application-lib',
  srcs = [APP_CLASS_SOURCE],
  deps = [
    ':build-config',
    ':jars__buck-android-support',
  ],
)

android_resource(
  name = 'res',
  package = 'de.danoeh.antennapod',
  res = 'res',
  assets = 'assets',
  deps = [
    ':appcompat',
    ':dslv-res',
  ]
)

android_library(
  name = 'dslv-lib',
  srcs = glob(['submodules/dslv/library/src/**/*.java']),
  deps = [
    ':all-jars',
    ':dslv-res',
  ],
)

android_resource(
  name = 'dslv-res',
  package = 'com.mobeta.android.dslv',
  res = 'submodules/dslv/library/res',
  deps = [
  ]
)

android_library(
  name = 'presto-lib',
  srcs = glob(['src/com/aocate/**/*.java']),
  deps = [
    ':presto-aidls',
    ':all-jars',
  ],
)

android_manifest(
  name = 'manifest',
  skeleton = 'AndroidManifest.xml',
  deps = [
    ':main-lib',
  ],
)

keystore(
  name = 'debug_keystore',
  store = 'keystore/debug.keystore',
  properties = 'keystore/debug.keystore.properties',
)

android_binary(
  name = 'antennapod',
  manifest = ':manifest',
  keystore = ':debug_keystore',
  use_split_dex = True,
  exopackage = True,
  primary_dex_patterns = [
    '^de/danoeh/antennapod/AppShell^',
    '^de/danoeh/antennapod/BuildConfig^',
    '^com/facebook/buck/android/support/exopackage/'
  ],
  deps = [
    ':main-lib',
    ':application-lib',
  ],
)


android_prebuilt_aar(
  name = 'appcompat',
  aar = 'libs/appcompat-v7-19.1.0.aar',
)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the library project I am trying to implement.

[image]

Here is the Buck file in the library project

```
prebuilt_jar(
  name = 'android-support-v4',
  binary_jar = 'android-support-v4.jar',
  visibility = [
    'PUBLIC',
  ],
)

prebuilt_jar(
  name = 'bolts',
  binary_jar = 'bolts.jar',
  visibility = [
    'PUBLIC',
  ],
)
```

Here is the best attempt build rules I have attempted.

```
### com.phonegap.plugins.facebook

android_library(
  name = 'facebook-plugin-java',
  srcs = glob(['com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/app-FacebookLib/src/**/*.java']),
)

android_resource(
  name = 'facebook-plugin-res',
  package = 'com.facebook',
  res = 'com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/app-FacebookLib/res',
)

facebook_plugin_jar_deps = []
for jarfile in glob(['com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/app-FacebookLib/libs/*.jar']):
  name = 'jars__' + re.sub(r'^.*/([^/]+)\.jar$', r'\1', jarfile)
  facebook_plugin_jar_deps.append(':' + name)
  prebuilt_jar(
    name = name,
    binary_jar = jarfile,
  )

android_library(
  name = 'facebook-plugin-jars',
  exported_deps = facebook_plugin_jar_deps,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that `BUCK` file, a [`prebuilt_jar`](https://buckbuild.com/rule/prebuilt_jar.html) rule is created for each `.jar` file Buck finds under `lib/`.  We add `support-v4-19.1.0.jar` under that folder in [this commit](https://github.com/facebookarchive/AntennaPod/commit/6c809273e70428f2f465cdeef568e1f35c30b439).  This is referenced as an `exported_dep` in the `//:all-jars` build target.  The `//:dslv-lib` build target takes a dependency on `//:all-jars`, so it ends up being a dependency that shows up in IntelliJ.

Comment: Ahh, `support-v4-19.1.0.jar` == `android-support-v4.jar`